# Deploying DialogFlow without asking it to go into your action first?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have various smart devices where if you say "turn off lights", it will just turn off my smart lights.

I'm learning to make my own agent on dialogflow but to run my test app in the simulator, I always have to type in "talk to my test app" first. Then subsequent operations are fine.

How do I deploy an agent where I can get it to skip the "talk to my test app" step? I would like to be able to access my agent without a trigger phrase.

Comment: Is this for the Google Assistant? Is this a Smart Home action or something else?

Comment: Yes, this is for google Assistant involving smart home actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a [Smart Home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) you should **not** be using Dialogflow. Dialogflow is one way to handle the Natural Language Understanding (NLU) for a [Conversational Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview).

Smart Home Actions have the NLU taken care of by Google directly. Instead, you should be defining the [device types and traits](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/devices-traits) those devices have. You'll then need to create a webhook that handles [specific intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/intents) for your device:

- SYNC - return what devices the user has
- QUERY - return the state of devices
- EXECUTE - change the device/trait state
- DISCONNECT - unregister a device